# Error: "Notice: Undefined index:" with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Here's my javascript code:

```
$( ".modifica_sore" ).click(function(){
var button = this;
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "action/modifica_professori.php",

  data: {               
            nome: $(button).siblings('[name="nome"]').attr("value"),
            cognome: $(button).siblings('[name="cognome"]').attr("value"),
            id: $(button).siblings('[name="id"]').attr("value"),
            modifica_sore: $(button).siblings('[name="modifica_sore"]').attr("value"),
  },
  dataType: "html",

  success: function(msg)
  {
    alert("Aggiunto con successo");
    $("#risultato").html(msg);
  },
  error: function()
  {
    alert("Chiamata fallita, si prega di riprovare...");  callback in caso di fallimento
  }
});
  });
```

And there's my form:

```
echo"<form method='POST'>";
echo"<fieldset>";
echo"<table>";
echo"<tr>";
   echo"<td>Nome</td>";
   echo"<td><input class='nome' name='nome' value='$nome'/></td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"<tr>";
   echo"<td>Cognome</td>";
   echo"<td><input class='cognome' name='cognome' value='$cognome'/></td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"<tr>";
   echo"<td></td>";
   echo"<td><input type='hidden' class='id' name='id' value='$id'/></td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"<tr>";
     echo "<td> <input type='button' name='modifica_sore' class='modifica_sore'  value='Modifica' /> </td>";
    echo "<td> <input type='button' name='modifica_sore' class='modifica_sore' value='Elimina' /> </td>";
echo"</tr>";
echo"</table>";
echo"</fieldset>";
echo"</form>";
```

If I don't use Ajax, it works, but with Ajax I have this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\action\modifica_professori.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: cognome in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\action\modifica_professori.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\action\modifica_professori.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: modifica_sore in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\action\modifica_professori.php on line 13

Notice: Undefined index: modifica_sore in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\action\modifica_professori.php on line 26
```

And in modifica_professori.php i use these $_POST var:

```
$nome = $_POST['nome'];
$cognome = $_POST['cognome'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
$_POST['modifica_sore']
```

But if it works without Ajax, the problem is in javascript... :/ Thank you for help...

Comment: print_r($_POST); look what that prints out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because `.modifica_sore` buttons don't have `<input>` elements with names like `"nome"` or `"cognome"` as their siblings. To get the value for `"nome"` you should use something like:

```
$(button).closest("table").find('[name="nome"]').val();
```

Comment: Or `$(button).closest("form").serialize();`

Comment: @Musa True, besides in this case there will be a problem with `.modifica_sore` elements.

Comment: you can also use `data : $(this).parents('form').serialize()`

Comment: @zgr024 No. `parents` will return a set of parent elements that come into `"form"` selector. Even if it will be only one element returned (since forms can't be nested), the `parents` method is not that effective in the current case.

Comment: @VisioN it is effective though it may not be the best option. He should just stick an id on the form and refer to it that way to avoid traversal anyway. `data: $('#someFormID').serialize()`

Comment: @zgr024 I tried, but I still have `Undefined index: modifica_sore`
@VisioN Thank you, it worked!

Comment: @VisioN Ok, now I don't have the notice anymore, but if I press the second button, it doesn't work.
I don't have any error (PHP or SQL too) and I get a confirm message, but nothing happens.

Comment: @TimuçinBeşkenPawiński Check that you have two buttons with the same names, and you probably get the value of the first button on every click, since they both correspond to `.modifica_sore` selector. Set different names to them, or use different logic to get the next value.

Answer (score 0):

There are no [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) of `.modifica_sore`, so form element values are not getting submitted correctly.

I would suggest adding an `id` attribute to the form and then using a selector like:

```
nome: $('#formid input[name="nome"]').attr('value')
cognome: $('#formid input[name="cognome"]').attr('value')
...
```

in your ajax data object.

**Edit:**

Since you mentioned you cannot modify the form, maybe you could try changing the selector to something like this:

```
var form = $(button).parents('form');

...
data: {
  nome: form.find('input[name="nome"]').attr('value'),
  cognome: form.find('input[name="cognome"]').attr('value'),
  ...
},
...
```

Comment: It is not true. There are no siblings of `.modifica_sore`.

Comment: I can't do that, because my form is generated from a database. 
I can't add an id.

Comment: @VisioN - Oops. You are correct, the matched selector is excluded from siblings(). Updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @Aiias I mean, that I have more than a form with same names. (using a "while").

Comment: @Timuçin Beşken Pawiński - I updated my answer to use a selector that will only take into account the current form.

Comment: @Timuçin Beşken Pawiński - What if you try `parents` instead of `parent`?